Use Apache-Camel 3 with Guice
I have a java application that uses Apache-Camel and Guice. I am trying to upgrade from Apache-camel v2 to v3 for JDK17 support. I see camel-guice package was deprecated and removed from camel 3. I am mainly extending CamelModuleWithMatchingRoutes to bind my route builders. How can I migrate to v3 while using Guice?
public class MyModule extends CamelModuleWithMatchingRoutes {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        super.configure();
        bind(routeBuilder1.class);
        bind(routeBuilder2.class);
    }
}

Checked migration guidelines but there were no mention of Guice deprecation or how to migrate Guice applications. https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3-migration-guide.html

There is no out of the box camel-guice component anymore. You need to migrate to something else such as Spring Boot or Quarkus. And you should jump to Camel v4, as v3 is EOL by end of this year.
